# Install Mono Offline

Tags: mono, centos7

I'm looking for offline installation package for mono on centOS or Redhat.
I want to run *.exe file on Linux.
All I find is using online repositories but my server is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say which version of Mono you are looking for, but you can manually download the most recent "stable" centOS `rpm` packages from:

- http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/

i.e. The current `mono-core` 64bit `.rpm` is under `m/mono-core`:

- http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/m/mono-core/mono-core-4.8.0.495-0.xamarin.1.x86_64.rpm

Once you have all the rpms that you need downloaded and copied to your offline server, you can use `yum` to install them...